# Restangular: long url with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to do such query url:

```
Restangular.one('company').one('manager').one(managerId).get(params)
```

which should be for example:

```
/company/manager/12/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

but something went wrong, and i get:

```
Error: You're creating a Restangular entity with the number instead of the route or the parent. For example, you can't call .one(12).
```

What i do wrong?

What is the best way of solving this issue?

sure, i can do this:

```
Restangular.one('company').one('manager/' + managerId).get(params)
```

but it's to ugly way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Restangular.one('company').one('manager', managerId).get(params)
```